# Can't download microsoft/windowsservercore image

Tags: docker

I'm consistently getting this error and download failure:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> docker run -ti microsoft/windowsservercore powershell
Unable to find image 'microsoft/windowsservercore:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from microsoft/windowsservercore
3889bb8d808b: Downloading [==================================================>]  4.07 GB/4.07 GB
423d66441981: Downloading [==================================================>] 1.203 GB/1.203 GB
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: read tcp 192.168.0.11:60315->72.21.81.200:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe run --help'.
```

I presume this is happening because of my slow connection speed (1Mbps). The hello-world:nanoserver sample downloads and works fine.

I don't mind downloading this as a BITS job, but I'll need to know two things:

1. The download URL
2. Where to save the file on my Hyper-V 2016 host server, so that Docker can load it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this can't be done. A Docker image isn't available for download as a single file, like a VHDX or some such other package.

The way to do it is to use `docker pull`, `docker save` and `docker load`.

```
docker pull hello-world:nanoserver
docker images
docker save 85cb186f58f4 -o .\Image.bin
copy '\\SERVER1\C$\Users\Admin\Image.bin' .
docker load -i .\Image.bin
docker image tag 85cb186f58f4 hello-world:nanoserver
```

If you're downloading (`pull`ing) on a fast network and moving the image to a slow one, substitute the `copy` command above to whatever means you prefer to get the `Image.bin` file from one place to another.